# How to get dataAxisToSRSAxisMapping from an image

Tags: python, coordinate-system, vrt

I'm working on lib to build VRT files in Python using only rasterio and avoid compatibility issue ([roi-vrt](https://github.com/12rambau/rio-vrt)). I started back from the spec (https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/vrt.html) but there are still some parameters that I don't really understand.

What is exactly [`dataAxisToSRSAxisMapping`](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/vrt.html#vrtdataset)  and how can this be extracted from a raster?